# Design a TagVisualization for a control dial

Tags: c#, wpf, pixelsense

I'd like to design a UI-Element, which gives the User the possibility to switch between different options. Therefore I want to use a Tangible which acts as control dial... I have already designed a Pointer and a Menu. The problem:

When the User rotates the Tangible, the Menu should stand still and the pointer should follow the rotation-movement. But when the User just moves the Tangible (without a rotation), the whole UI-Element should move.

Here a example for a non-Tangible control dial:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee804832%28v=surface.10%29.aspx

Does anyone know how to deal this with a TagVisualization?

Thanks in advance,

Chris

EDIT:

I've written a small tutorial, which can be viewed on: http://project-premium.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set UsesTagOrientation=false on the TagVisualization or TagVisualizationDefinition

Inside the TagVisualization, monitor TrackedContact.Orientation to update your dial UI